# Displaying single line progress during Django management command and disabling it during tests

Tags: python, django, testing

I have some Django management commands which call methods in other classes to perform various tasks, like fetching data from external APIs.

In those methods I'm outputting a single line that displays progress, something like:

```
print('Fetched %d of %d' % (n, total) + ' '*30, end='\r')
```

That works fine, but when I run my tests this gets printed out and screws up the `.....E....F...` display. I could patch `print` in all my tests, but that seems clunky.

So (a) should I be outputting that progress line some other way, and/or (b) is there a better way to suppress that output while running tests?

Comment: you can have your own wrapper around print, which will check if sys.stdout is a terminal or not and depending on it behave differently, e.g. \r for terminal \n for file or pipe

Answer (score 1):

The first step is actually to get rid of print statements and replace it with [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/).

With django logging you get far more control than you do with print and it isn't hard to setup. Two of the key features is that you can control whether log messages goto a file or the console. You can also further fine tune it based on the DEBUG flag.

You probably need this messages to appear only on your dev server and not in production. So logging can help you there. And more importantly when tests are run it switches off the debug flag so your .....E....F will not be cluttered.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure about using logging for this, although happy to be corrected! First, these print statements are only used for code that's run from the command line with management commands, so it's fine if they happen on the live server. Second, they're used to print a single line whose figures update with progress - can logging do that?

Comment: yes. Think of logging as the more refined and enhanced version of print.

Comment: I've got some logging working but I can't see how to overwrite the previous line in the console, like I can with `print('hello', end='\r')`.

Comment: I don't know that one either. but does it matter?

Comment: Yes - If I'm displaying the progress of a task that takes an hour, fetching 3000 items from an API, then I'd like to have a single line that updates, rather than filling up 3000 lines of the console (or 300 if I only updated every 10, etc).

Comment: Well you didn't say that in your question.

Comment: I guess "I'm outputting a single line that displays progress", and the use of `print('...', end="\r")` wasn't explicit enough, sorry.

Comment: yeah, fair enough, sorry that I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks for trying :)